# Should deployment questions be asked on Stack Overflow or Server Fault?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, site-recommendation, serverfault

I'm not sure where to ask a deployment question, Stack Overflow or Server Fault. It's kind of a crossover question.

I need to be able to sort out the server requirements for deploying a click once app. I thought that my server had all the required attributes, but I am having issues, which sort of implies a serverfault.com question. However it's very likely that only a .NET dev would be able to answer me.

Where do you think I should ask my question?

Comment: lol - I asked this 4 years before the other one. Maybe that one should have been marked duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is pretty clearly a StackOverflow question. The people on ServerFault may *run* the servers that the app's being deployed to, but I don't think many handle deployment issues.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you can't ask on both sites - simply state you've asked in both places. (This has happened several times that I can recall) At worst you'll get two different audiences giving you possible answers. However as Jeff pointed out - try one first and if you get a lukewarm response, then try the other site.

If you think it's something a .NET dev would be able to answer - ask on StackOverflow first but there is a lot more overlap between Server Fault and Stack Overflow than you would think.

Comment: I would not encourage this -- ask first on whichever site you feel is most appropriate. If after a few days the reception is lukewarm, *then* try the other site.